Некорректно собирается jar-файл: no main manifest attribute
Собранный в идее (Intellij IDEA) jar-файл не запускается со следующей ошибкой:
no main manifest attribute, in .../MyJarFilename.jar
Запускать пробую следующей командой: java -jar MyJarFilename.jar.
MANIFEST.MF выглядит следующим образом:
Manifest-Version: 2.0
Main-Class: lobaevni.et.MainKt
Class-Path: lobaevni.et

build.gradle.kts выглядит следующим образом:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.20"
    application
}

group = "lobaevni.et"
version = "2.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    # тут ещё куча всяких зависимостей, не суть...

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-cli:0.3.5")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.7.3")

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:3.0.0-rc-1")

    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.16")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.9.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}

Собираю jar-файл в идее через меню Build -> Build artifacts -> Build. Предварительно в File -> Project Structure -> Project settings -> Artifacts добавил конфигурацию для сборки JAR -> From modules with dependencies.
Пересмотрел огромное количество документаций, всяких ответов на форумах по подобной проблеме, но решения так и не нашёл. Пробовал добавлять следующие строки в свой build.gradle.kts, но это не решало проблему:
application {
    mainClass.set("lobaevni.et.MainKt")
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "lobaevni.et.MainKt"
        attributes["Class-Path"] = "lobaevni.et"
    }
}

Пробовал полностью чистить кеши идеи, перезапускать её, удалять папки с билдами и т.д. - тоже ни на что не влияло.
Я сразу отмечу, что я не силён в тонкостях сборки и gradle. Я понимаю процесс сборки так, что в мой jar-файл кладутся собранные подключённые библиотеки, которые я использовал в своей программе, также собранная моя программа, и в этом jar-файле это всё аккуратно линкуется с помощью манифеста, в котором собственно и прописывается инструкция для запуска, чтобы java понимала, какой класс является точкой входа (ну это если прям грубо говоря, я просто на пальцах объяснил, как я это всё понимаю). Вот только не доходит никак до java, где лежит мой заветный Main.kt с функцией main.
Кстати, сам Main.kt выглядит следующим образом (это я уж на всякий случай прикрепил, package указан):
package lobaevni.et

...

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ...
}


Classpath какой-то странный

@talexmovedtoCodidact ну, такой package в моём проекте. Не знаю, как по-другому должен выглядеть.

Обычно он выглядит как список jar файлов.

@talexmovedtoCodidact у меня только один jar-файл собирается. Остальные jar-файлы - я так понимаю имеются ввиду уже собранные используемые в моём проекте jar-файлы библиотек - я подключил библиотеки через build.gradle.kts. Их разве нужно все вручную перечислять в Class-Path для сборки jar-файла проекта?

Вообще я Class-Path сам указал в качестве эксперимента, его вообще не было изначально, когда я только создал проект в идее. Я пробовал его не указывать и как будто это ни на что не повлияло - ошибка при запуске jar-файла была та же.

В jar  файле есть файл с именем lobaevni/et/MainKt.class?

@talexmovedtoCodidact да, есть.

Мне кажется я понял, в чём проблема - в моём собранном jar-файле файл MANIFEST.MF выглядит не так, как локально в проекте в папке resources - в нём указано только Manifest-Version: 1.0, а поле Main-Class куда-то пропало. Но ещё помимо собранного jar-файла в папке out/production/resources/META-INF у меня лежит ещё один MANIFEST.MF, который уже в точности совпадает с моим resources/MANIFEST.MF. Как это всё понимать - не знаю. И как сделать так, чтобы в jar-файле был нужный MANIFEST.MF с ожидаемым содержимым - тоже пока не знаю.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html?section=Gradle%20Kotlin#run-the-jar - здесь полное актуальное описание, как правильно собирать jar-файл. Указал дополнительные инструкции в build.gradle.kts, jar-файл успешно собрался и теперь запускается как надо. Я раньше по другим инструкциям собирал, как указал в вопросе - так не работает.

Кстати, сейчас ещё выяснил, что если в проекте несколько модулей, то этой инструкции будет недостаточно: нужно обязательно в основной модуль (главный, который будет запускаемым) добавить в build.gradle.kts зависимости из всех остальных модулей, хотя бы через compileOnly. Почему проект успешно собирается в идее, а jar не собирается - я без понятия. Оставил себе и другим заметку на будущее : )
